# Grafana - Updated all graphs on dashboard from metric selection

Tags: jenkins, grafana, prometheus

I have a prometheus node which collects job data from Jenkins and stores it e.g.:

```
jenkins_job_last_completed_build_queuing_duration_seconds{jobname="j1"} 0.01
jenkins_job_last_completed_build_timestamp_seconds{jobname="j1"} 1489006588.334
```

etc.

In grafana I want ot have a dashboard with a bunch of graphs for the different metrics and some way of choosing which job to display on the graphs.
e.g.
I log onto the dashboard and select j1 somehow and all the graphs show the data for j1.
Then I change my selection to j2 and all the graphs update to show j2 data.

I know I can do this on a per graph basis by clicking in the legend, but I want to do them all at once.

Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!  You can make a template query in grafana that is populated with a label value.  Docs are here: http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#templated-queries

We do something similar to select a namespace in a dashboard to see the memory & CPU consumption of the services in that namespace.  Our dashboard looks like this:

[image]

And the queries look like:

`namespace_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{namespace=\"$namespace\"}`

I don't know how to make the variable with the UI, I generate the config with our grafanalib project (https://github.com/weaveworks/grafanalib) and it looks like this:

`"templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "allValue": null,
        "current": {
          "tags": [],
          "text": "default",
          "value": "default"
        },
        "datasource": "Scope-as-a-Service Prometheus",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": false,
        "label": "Namespace",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "namespace",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(k8s_pod_status_ready, namespace)",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "sort": 1,
        "tagValuesQuery": null,
        "tagsQuery": null,
        "type": "query"
      }
    ]
  },`

Comment: Thanks this worked nicely.
To add a template in the GUI, on the dashboard click the cog icon in the top menu bar and choose templating.  From there you can manually create a template :)